# Angular js filter: notarray, list populated via ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have created a list with ng-repeat directive and would like to filter it with ng-options directive. However, no matter if filter is initialised in scope as an empty array or as an empty object, I get an error: [filter: notarray]. I have tried different approaches for the select dropdown, however I had been still getting the same error:

Here is my filter:

```
<select name="project-filter" id="" ng-model="projectFilter" ng-options="task.project for task in tasksList">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

Here is the list I would like to filter:

```
<li ng-repeat='task in tasksList | filter : projectFilter' class="list-element">
    <a href="" ng-click="taskDetails()">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="name-and-date">
              <span class="task-name">{{task.name}}</span> <span class="due-date">{{task.dueDate}}</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="additional-info">
              <span>{{task.project}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a> 
</li>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
angular.module('toDoApp')

.controller('mainController', function($scope, $rootScope, saveTaskService, retrieveTasksFactory) {
    var newTaskPopUp = document.getElementById('new-task-pop-up'),
        filterProjecTypeDropdown = document.getElementById('filter-project-type-dropdown');
    $scope.task = {
        name: '',
        project: '',
        dueDate: '',
        priority: '',
        tags: '',
        parent: '',
        comments: '',
        reminders: ''
    };

    $scope.projectFilter = {};

    $scope.showList = false;

    $rootScope.tasksList = {};
    retrieveTasksFactory.getTasksList()
    .then(function (tasks) {
        $rootScope.tasksList = tasks;
        if (tasks.length > 0) $scope.showList = true;
        console.log($rootScope.tasksList);
    }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Could somebody explain me what am I doing wrong or missing? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: It looks like you need to add `$rootScope` to your `ng-repeat`, ie: `ng-repeat='task in $rootScope.tasksList | filter : projectFilter'`

Comment: kennypowers is right, but you also might want to avoid using rootScope, and use a normal $scope

Comment: It did not help. When I had changed `ng-repeat` definition to use `$rootScope`  it did not generate the list of tasks. Currently it shows records in list.